# Is there anything you can do in C++ that you cannot do in C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to figure out if there is anything that you can do in c++ that you absolutely cannot do in c#?

I know that there are platforms that are targeted to native libraries, but I want to know if the lowest level c# can compare with the lowest level c++.

Comment: You can't create a class template, define an ordinal generic parameter, define parameterised macros, conditionally include different headers (or include headers at all, for that matter). You'll need to be a bit more specific if you want a meaningful answer.

Comment: There are about a thousand ways of provoking undefined behavior in C++ that don't work in C# (even with `unsafe`). Is that the sort of thing you mean? ;-)

Comment: In kernel-mode driver development C++ may be problematic. It's related to the fact that C++ generates some "hidden" code. Whereas in kernel mode it may be critical to know where all your code resides. For instance, a driver can contain both paged and non-paged code.

Comment: Let me try to translate as well as i can, what one of our (Polish) journalists - Stefan Kisielewski once said about a political system, we had a misfortune to experiment with. "Socialism is a system, in which heroic effort is being put in, to overcome problems... unknown in any other system." With C++ it's kinda similar. It's an extremely expressive and powerful programming language, that provides the tools, allowing to tackle and solve problems of unimaginable complexity. ... Problems non-existent in any other programming language.

Comment: I would like one of the people who closed this to explain exactly how the subject is subjective and/or argumentative.  Seems pretty technical and fact driven to me.  Sure, the question isn't phrased very well, but the close reason is BS.

Comment: I guess the most low-level stuff you can do is modifying the bytes directly on the stack.  Is there anything more low-level than that?

Comment: @Ed: I closed it as not a real question. I can't believe it managed "subjective and argumentative" - I hope it was at least 3-2 not 4-1. I can see how it'd get argumentative (people can be zealots about their favorite languages). But subjective? (And when I closed it, the second paragraph wasn't there. The scope was definitely way too broad.)

Comment: @wcpro: I'm just about willing to reopen this. I think you might want to edit it a little more first, though - compare for example Ed Swangren's and Caleb's answers. Ed's is about end results, while Caleb's is about details of the language. I'm guessing you're looking more for answers like Ed's. Be clear!

Comment: @Jefromi: Yeah, I've seen that happen before.  I can sort of understand closing it as "not a real question" due to the small amount of effort put into the question and poor phrasing.

Comment: Please don't reopen this. If allowed it *assures* the existence of an arbitrary number of *"What can I do in FooLang that I can't do in LangBar?"* questions. As such it would be worse than "Hidden Features" because the number of available questions is squared. NB: That this follow the now closed and deleted [Can you do something in C that would not be possible in C++? (10k only)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008563/) is something that I regard as evidence for my case

Comment: I didn't mean for this to be argumentative, i honestly have never programmed in c++ and I hear that you can do more.  Im sorry if the question wasn't phrased very well, but i thing this page is a great source of knowledge.

Comment: i don't care do what you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Device drivers.  These applications operate in kernel mode, and .NET apps don't (they run in user mode).  Even if you could, would you really want to?  Probably not considering the overhead of the runtime and the relative difficulty of interfacing directly to hardware devices.

In software you can pretty much do anything given enough time and effort.  It comes down to whether or not a certain task is practical rather than possible.

Answer (score 2):

Write [Real Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode) code. There is no CIL framework that runs in real mode, therefore C# cannot target it. C++ has been able to target real mode for decades now.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Servy: It really isn't a comment. There is currently no (and probably never will be a) C# compiler that targets real mode; all of them require protected or long mode due to the nature of .NET/Mono.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The point is that this is not sufficiently comprehensive to be an answer.  IF you discussed, in more detail, what it is, why it can be done in C++ and not C#, what the significance of it is, etc. then it could be made into an answer.  Just mentioning, "Real Mode" alone is a comment.

Answer (score 2):

inline assembler

there are some very complex win32 signatures that cannot be used via p/invoke; the sspi security interfaces for example

Answer (score 1):

You can't use multiple inheritance in C# (Excluding interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can overload more operators: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B vs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, C# handles all the memory management, so you're limited in terms of hands on memory management. This isn't really a bad thing though, as it takes a lot of work away from you as the coder. It becomes a bad thing if you're heavily concerned with performance (games and the likes).